# CSS not being rendered in the platform independent application for android

Tags: android, html, css, cross-platform

I have created an HTML document with CSS. When I open the HTML in the browser, the CSS is rendered perfectly as shown below:

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title> Platform Independent Application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="navbar-text" id="Employee Name"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span> Welcome   ABC</p>
    </div>
 </nav>

</head>
<body>
<form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Time Sheet Filled
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Shift Allowance Claimed
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
 </div>
 </form>
 <div class="basicinfo">
 <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading"> Basic Information </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Name: ABC
    <br>
    Employee id: 68292902
    <br>
    Manager: XXX
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

When I use the same code in an android application, the CSS does not get rendered.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title> Platform Independent Application</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="navbar-text" id="Employee Name"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span> Welcome   ABC</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    -->
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox1">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Time Sheet Filled
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox2">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Shift Allowance Claimed
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="basicinfo">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"> Basic Information </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Name: ABC
                <br>
                Employee id: 68292902
                <br>
                Manager: XXX
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>enter image description here
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Q) What should I modify/correct to get an output similar to the browser output ?

Comment: "When I use the same code in an android application" -- please provide a [mcve] showing how you use this HTML in an Android app. For example, where is the HTML coming from? That will help determine if your relative CSS paths resolve.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Your question actually solved my issue. I had mentioned wrong paths. Thanks :)